# partialrefreshPost with passing variable

Tags: javascript, xpages

I had a function for partialrefresh and wanted to reuse it by passing different page's id but it won't work. Is that i had this script wrong or partialrefresh couldn't except variable?

```
function ReloadPageId(Id) {
   XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:" + Id + "}", {});
}
```

Comment: What does "it won't work" mean?  Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I mean it didn't refresh as expected, either response any error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is not working because your `Id` variable is undefined at the time the Expression Language `"#{id:}"` is computed.

When you pass `Id' into your ReloadPageId function it already has to be computed. To grab the computed Id using client side javascript try putting an input tag on your XPage like this:

`<input id="getID" type="hidden" value="#{id:theIdYouWant}" />`

Then you call your function like this:

`ReloadPageId(document.getElementById("getID").value);`

And lastly your function will look like this:

```
function ReloadPageId(Id) {
   XSP.partialRefreshPost(Id);
}
```

Comment: Yes, "#{id:...}" gets calculated on server already whereas the execution is on client side. Instead of using input field I'd just call the function with `ReloadPageId("#{id:theIdYouWant}")` wherever you need it in your CSJS code.

Comment: @KnutHerrmann Thanks for adding that. I got in the habit of using the input field as a workaround to "#{id:...}" not being evaluated in script libraries.